# Add black outline geom_point and fill independent variable different from others

Tags: r, ggplot2

1. How can I add a black outline to all points? -> I have tried:
   `geom_point(aes(size = scaled_val, colour = value), colour "black")`  - but it turns the filling black. Also I have tried adding another: `geom_point(colour= "black"`) but it plots black points on top of the scaled points
2. Can I ignore the colour by value for one of the variables? (ie: I would like variable C to be ploted in size as scaled value like it is, but ignore the colouring by value and have an independent colour (black))

> ```
> data <- tibble::tibble(
>   value = c(4.07, 5.76, 2.87,4.94,5.48, 6.75,1.53,1.35, 1.32), 
>   Variable = rep(c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3), rep("C",3))),
>   Experiment = rep(c(1:3),3))
>
> data <- data %>%group_by(Variable)%>%
>   mutate(scaled_val = scale(value)) %>%
>   ungroup()
>
> data$Variable <- factor(data$Variable,levels=rev(unique(data$Variable)))
>
> ggplot(data, aes(x = Experiment, y = Variable, label=NA)) +
>   geom_point(aes(size = scaled_val, colour = value)) + 
>   geom_text(hjust = 1, size = 2) +
>   theme_bw()+
>   scale_color_gradient(low = "lightblue", high = "darkblue")+
>   scale_x_discrete(expand=c(1,0))+
>   coord_fixed(ratio=4)
> ```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use `geom_point(..., shape = 21)`

Comment: Yep.  [See this](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-point-shapes).  `shape` 21 through 25 are all outlined points which have a `fill=` and an outline (`color=`).

Comment: The solution is to add another geom_point such as: ``geom_point(aes(size = scaled_val, colour = value), shape=21, colour="black") +``